# Difference between sizeof(struct structname) and sizeof(object) in C

Tags: c, sizeof

Are there scenarios where there can be a difference between `sizeof(struct structure_name)` and `sizeof(object)` where `object` is of type `struct structure_name` in C?

Answer (score 7):

No there is no difference between `sizeof(type)` and `sizeof(o)` where the **declared** type of `o` is `type`.

There can be differences if the declared type of the object isn't truly representative of the object.  For example

```
char arrayValue[100];
sizeof(arrayValue);  // 100 on most systems
char* pointerValue = arrayValue;
sizeof(pointerValue);  // 4 on most 32 bit systems
```

This difference occurs because `sizeof` is a compile time construct in C.  Hence there is no runtime analysis and the compiler looks instead at the statically declared types.

Comment: A `char *x` is a very different type from `char y[100]`, even though in many cases, an expression involving `y` ends up as a `char *`.  Of course, one of the exceptions is `sizeof`; `sizeof(x) != sizeof(y)` on any plausible system (although theoretically the size of a pointer could be 100 bytes, it is pretty unlikely to be a problem in any of our lifetimes).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree they are very different types.  The OP appears new to C and i wanted to illustrate what I thought was one of the more common pitfalls when developers start using `sizeof` on values.

Answer (score 3):

No; `sizeof(type)` and `sizeof(object-of-type)` produce the same result at all times.

Well, there's a caveat that with a VLA (variable-length array), the `sizeof()` might be a run-time operation, but otherwise, they are fixed.  And you can make a case that even with a VLA, the result of `sizeof(variably-qualified-type)` and `sizeof(object-of-same-variably-qualified-type)` will produce the same result, so VLAs are not really an exception.

Comment: Really, can `sizeof` be a run-time operation?

Comment: In C99, yes: `sizeof()` can be a run-time operation:  `void minimal(int n) { int array[n]; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(array)); ... }`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's interesting. Didn't think that was allowed

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very interesting. Even I didn't think that was allowed, but it is allowed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler on this note, what's the difference btw `sizeof(struct NAME *)` and `sizeof(struct NAME)`?

Comment: What’s the difference between the size of a structure and the size of a pointer, @ShayanAmani?